# How to write a XPath for the text one4

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0

I want to use XPath to locate a link behind a text.

I want to use XPath to locate a link behind a text. For example, locate "one4" by "what10". You can only use the text message "what10", but you can't use it in any other way, because the information on this page will change. I want to get is the "one4" link node.

```html
<body>
<p>
<a href="/dy/dy5.jsp?funid=50">so</a>
<br>what1 <a href="/dy/dy5.jsp?funid=34+">one</a>
<br>what2<a href="/dy/dy5.jsp?funid=35+">two</a>
<br>what11<a href="/dy/dy5.jsp?funid=43+">one4</a>
<br>what3<a href="/dy/dy5.jsp?funid=36+">three</a>
<br>what4<a href="/dy/dy5.jsp?funid=37+">one1</a>
<br>what5<a href="/dy/dy5.jsp?funid=38+">two2</a>
<br>what6<a href="/dy/dy5.jsp?funid=39+">three3</a>
<br>what7<a href="/dy/dy5.jsp?funid=40+">one3</a>
<br>what8<a href="/dy/dy5.jsp?funid=41+">two3</a>
<br>what9<a href="/dy/dy5.jsp?funid=42+">three3</a>
<br>what10<a href="/dy/dy5.jsp?funid=43+">one4</a>
<br><a href="/dy/dy5.jsp?funid=44+">just return</a>
<br></p>
</body>
```

For some special reasons, what I want to pass is that the text of what10 is positioned to one4.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium doesn't supports `xpath-2.0` but uses `xpath-1.0`

The element which you are trying to refer i.e. which contains the text **what10** is a *Text Node* and *Selenium* can't use it as a reference. So finding the node with text as **one4** with reference to the text **what10** won't be possible. As an alternative if the desired node is always the *last but one* node you can use the following solution:

- *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/p//a[position()=last()-1]"));
  ```

### Update

As per @MosheSlavin counter question here is the snapshot to demonstrate that the *XPath* works perfecto:

[image: xpath_position]

Comment: You are right "Text Node and Selenium can't use it as a reference" yet the xpath you posted doesn't work either...

Comment: @MosheSlavin _...the xpath you posted doesn't work..._ Not sure what exactly you meant by **doesn't work**. Do you see any error? I have updated the answer with a snapshot to demonstrate how the _xpath_ exactly identifies the node perfecto. Let me know if you questions.

Comment: I know! I used `linkText` at first yet OP wanted it to be linked to the text so I tried yet my XPath did not work I tried your's: http://xpather.com/B2MYU9Ul and it did not work for some reason... I did not delete my answer because I the main part is the `getAttribute`... I would like to know with what tool do you test the xpaths?

Comment: @DebanjanB But sometimes the last `< a >` on this page is not what I want. This page can only judge **one4** based on **what10**.

Comment: @什么神奇 I have explained why you can't use the node with text as **what10** as a reference. Btw, the xpath in the answer is not the **last** but **`last but one`** node.

Comment: @什么神奇 Isn't the attribute value **43+** unique for the desired element with text as **one4**?

Comment: @DebanjanB no,this **43+** will change

Comment: Possibly you still need to update us/question about your usecase as there are 2 nodes with text as **one4** associated with **what11** and **what10** :)

Comment: @DebanjanB Because the elements that appear on this page are random, there may be one or two or more elements of this "one4". And the location of this "one4" is also random. But I want "one4" which has a feature that appears behind "what10". Only this one4 that appears after "what10" is what I want. I think selenium may not be able to do it. . . .

Answer (score 0):

You can use below line

```
WebElement loginLink = driver.findElement(By.linkText("one4"));
```